# Magento 2.1.6 Readiness check when installing new extension

Tags: magento-2.1

I've installed the latest version of magento community edition via composer and all is working fine until i want to install an extension. I get the following:

> PHP Version Check
> Your PHP version is . The required PHP version is . Show detail
>
> PHP Settings Check *
> PHP Extensions Check
> missing PHP extensions. Hide detail
>
> The best way to resolve this is to install the correct missing extensions. The >exact fix depends on our server, your host, and other system variables.
> Our PHP extension help can get you started.

I have gone over the server settings and have checked there is no variation on php versions which is currently on 7.0.17 all sites under this server are running the same. I've exhausted all options which i've found online such as modifying composer.json and there's no need for always_populate_raw_post_data=-1 as it's removed in PHP7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to run these 3 command  in terminal and after that try to install extension:

/bin/magento cron:run

/update/cron.php

/bin/magento setup:cron:run

Comment: Worked like a charm. Spent 2 days trying to sort this out. Thank you